# How to pass react value to Node.js api call

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make api call to riot api but for some reason am getting `500  internal server error`.

I am passing values from react but 
   my server value is being  not passed to backend,  I can see that in network tab. I only see on parameter.   **I'm getting correct value for server in the console i have checked it**. But am not sure why I'm not seeing it in `network tab`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class NavigatioBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
      currentUser: null,
      redirect: false,
      email: '',
      name: '',
      elo: '',
      value2: '',
      isOpen: false
    }

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.signout = this.signout.bind(this);
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value2: event.target.value });
  }

  searchChampions(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.value2);
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/search-champ", {
      method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({
        champname:this.refs.query.value,
        server: this.refs.query.value2
         })
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log("search result is + ", data)
    })
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <div className='zipcodeInput'>
        <form>
          <input ref="query" 
                 type='text' 
                 placeholder='Enter zipcode..' 
                 name='name'/>
          <button onClick={this.searchChampions.bind(this)}> 
            ENTER
          </button>
        </form>
      <select value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="EUW">EUW</option>
        <option value="NA">NA</option>
        <option value="EUNE">EUNE</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

and my backend is like so 
server.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = (app) => {

    let champname;
    let server;

    app.post('/search-champ', (req, res) => {
        champname = req.body.champname;   //added by hu
        server = req.body.server; 
        //need to call api to get champions
        const apiId = 'RGAPI-397a1d41-77f8-44b1-93df-021851be2ac1';
        const baseUrl = 'https://'+ server+'/api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+ champname + '?api_key='+apiId;

        const userLocation = (url1, url2, champname) => {

            let newUrl = url1 + champname + url2;
            return newUrl;
        };

        const apiUrl = 'https://'+ server+'/api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+ champname + '?api_key='+apiId;

        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                var id = data.id;

                const apiUrl2 = 'https://'+ server+'/api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v3/active-games/by-summoner/'+id+ '?api_key='+apiId;;

                fetch(apiUrl2)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    res.send({ data });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.redirect('/error');
                });

            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.redirect('/error');
            });



    })
    app.get('/search-location-champ', (req, res) => {
        //build api URL with user zip
        const apiId = 'RGAPI-4b602b1a-e6aa-4c24-b88f-d0aab6467fa8';
        const baseUrl = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+ champname + '?api_key='+apiId;


        const userLocation = (url1, url2, champname) => {

            let newUrl = url1 + champname + url2;
            return newUrl;
        };

        const apiUrl = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/'+ champname + '?api_key='+apiId;

        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                res.send({ data });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.redirect('/error');
            });
    })
}
```

Comment: You may want to remove that apiId if that is something that can be missused

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending data by `json.stringify()` so you may need to parse it in server

```
 app.post('/search-champ', (req, res) => {

    champname = JSON.parse(req.body).champname;   //change here
    server = JSON.parse(req.body).server; //change here
    //need to call api to get champions
```

Or you can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). `npm install --save axios`

```
searchChampions(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.value2);
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/search-champ", {
                                       champname:this.refs.query.value,
                                       server: this.refs.query.value2
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log("search result is + ", data)
    })
}
```